# Encoding issue in command line but not in eclipse output

Tags: java, character-encoding, log4j

Well,
I'm running a spring boot app with some arguments like this :

My method is :

```java
public static String getParam(String args) {
    String param = args.substring(args.indexOf("=")+1);
    log.info("Argument détécté : "+param);
    return param;
}
```

but my output is :

```
test.dialog.DialogApplication         : Argument dÚtÚctÚ : XXXX
test.dialog.DialogApplication         : Argument dÚtÚctÚ : YYYY
```

My execution call is :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--param=XXXX,--param2=YYYY
```

But if I run it through eclipse :

```
test.dialog.DialogApplication       Argument détécté : XXXX
```

May someone explain me why encoding seemns different between command line and eclipse STS4 output and if possible how to get nice accentued logs :-)

PS : i'm running on Win10

Comment: Are you running on Linux or Windows command line? If Linux what does `locale` command print?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki added it to the post, i'm on w10

Answer (score 0):

Encodings need to be supported by the outputting programm aswell.

Eclipse does support UTF-8 (usually the default setting) hence the output is correctly displayed. For command line it depends on the console you run `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--param=XXXX,--param2=YYYY` in.